# Print currency symbol properly

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, "Polish")
current_locale = locale.localeconv()
print current_locale["currency_symbol"]
```

There result is:

```
z�
```

However Polish currency symbol is 'zł', so 'ł' is badly printed as '�'. How to print it correctly?

Comment: Is your console set as UTF-8?

Comment: I guess so: print "ąśćäåńêëł" is printed correctly

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` does nothing in your case. It is only relevant for [literal strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What console are you using?
Windows command prompt and many IDEs do not properly support UTF8. 
Try running your code in IDLE's python shell or writing the answer to a text file in UTF with the codecs module.